# error listing aws multi prefixes to get key contents value

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

**Code**

```
import boto3
from boto3 import client
 
prefix=("env:/A", "env:/B")
conn = client('s3')
for path in prefix:
    print(path)
    for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket="my_bucket",
                             Prefix=path)['Contents']:
                print(key)
```

**Error:**

env:/A

Key1....content ok

Key2....content ok

env:/B
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/listB.py", line 8, in 
for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket="my_bucket",
KeyError: 'Contents'

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you got the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing has been returned, thus there is no `Contents`. You should check for that:

```
from boto3 import client
 
prefix=("env:/A", "env:/B")
conn = client('s3')

for path in prefix:

    print(path)

    result = conn.list_objects(
                Bucket="my_bucket",
                Prefix=path)

    if 'Contents' in result:
        content = result['Contents']
        # process content if there is any
```